# Modified extension affecting the behavior of other tabs

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I've modified an extension for some testing. Without going into too much details, its function is to refresh the tab its activated on by going to a specified website every set number of seconds. However, it seems to weirdly change any other tab that's open to the one specified in the extension. For example, I've two tabs open, one has the extension activated which is refreshing the tab by directing to facebook.com, the other has Google open. After a couple of seconds, the tab with google.com will also start directing to facebook.com. So, no matter how many different tabs I open, they will eventually all become facebook.com.

What can I do here?

I was trying to modify an extension to test something. It works as expected except for the one weird bug explained above. This is the code I used:

```
// Listen for the return to initial page request from content.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.action === "returnToInitial") {
        // Navigate the tab back to the initial URL
        // (Assuming a predefined initialURL; this should be dynamically set based on user's preferences)
        let initialURL = "https://facebook.com";  // Placeholder URL
        chrome.tabs.update(sender.tab.id, {url: initialURL});
    }
});
```

Comment: It means that the message is sent by all those tabs, not just the selected one. You need to add a condition to compare sender.tab.id to the tab's id configured by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to get the current tab. [From documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#get-the-current-tab)

```
async function getCurrentTab() {
  let queryOptions = { active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true };
  // `tab` will either be a `tabs.Tab` instance or `undefined`.
  let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query(queryOptions);
  return tab;
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I need! Thanks a lot.